# UI not responding on screen orientation -Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application with mediaplayer. I have handled screen orientation with two layouts. I have used onsavedInstancestate and onrestoreinstancesstate. On screen rotation the layout changes and the mediaplayer state is retained but UI is not responding.

I have saved and retained the state of mediaplayer object

```
   public  Object  onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() 
         {
                HashMap<String,Object> player = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                MediaPlayer instance = mp;
                mp = null;
                MediaPlayer instance1 = mp1;
                mp1 = null;
                player.put("mp", instance);
                player.put("mp1", instance1);
                return player;

          }

 if(getLastNonConfigurationInstance()!=null)
                {

                 playerhandle = (HashMap<String, Object>) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
                 mp = (MediaPlayer)playerhandle.get("mp");
                 if (mp == null) 
                 {
                    mp = new MediaPlayer();
                 }
                 mp1 = (MediaPlayer)playerhandle.get("mp1");
                 if (mp1 == null) 
                 {
                   mp1 = new MediaPlayer();
                 }
                 }
```

and also  retained the data with onsavedinstancestate and onrestoreinstancestate .The mediaplayer retains the state after screen orientation(audio plays without interpretation on screen orientation) but the UI is not responding after orientation change. Unable to figure out the problem .....

Comment: i have edited the question ..please provide with suggestions